# WSO2 EI Analytics Profile Database configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm configuring WSO2 EI Analytics profile to use PostgreSQL instead of H2 database.

I have changed the following files:

analytics-datasources.xml,

master-datasources.xml,

metrics-datasources.xml

in ***\wso2\analytics\conf\datasources***. 
I have, also, executed the scripts to create the database in *dbscripts*. **The scripts generate only tables for metrics and master, but they do not create tables for analytics.**

Anyway when I run the analytics server i have some errors as shown below:

```
Failed to perform Category Drilldown on table: org_wso2_esb_analytics_stream_MediatorStatPerMinute: Error while connecting to the remote service. Connection refused (Connection refused) {JAGGERY.controllers.apis.eianalytics:jag}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-06 16:43:00,262] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 present in cache 
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
    ... 7 more
```

**It seems they are missing some database tables, but i don't know how to create them.**

These errors are not present when i use H2 database with the default configuration.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.
It was a JDBC driver problem.

With JDK 1.8 it is necessary to use the PostgreSQL JDBC 42.1.4.

I hope it will be useful for someone.